# Click through an image that fades on MouseOver?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image that fades out on MouseOver. I'd like to place some text and links behind the image, but the links aren't clickable. I can't use `pointer-events: none` either, because it would break the fading effect.

The image should also fade back in on MouseOut.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/e96nbowc/

HTML

```
<div class="cover">

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9Z5ODyg.png"/>

    <a href="test1">Test 1</a><br/>
    <a href="test2">Test 2</a><br/>
    <a href="test3">Test 3</a><br/>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.cover {
    position: relative;    
    width: 300px; height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.cover img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.cover img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.cover img {
  position: absolute;
  transition:.5s ease;
}

.cover:hover img {
   opacity: 0;
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e96nbowc/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not position the text in front of the image, but opacity 0, then fade the text in at the same time as you fade out the image, giving the illusion of the text being behind?